# like application from js sdk like button

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm currently building an app where you can like the app itself from a like button inside the frame. So, i load the js sdk :

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
       appId      : '<?php echo $appid; ?>', // App ID
       status     : true, 
       cookie     : true,
       xfbml      : true,
       oauth      : true,
    });
    FB.Canvas.setSize()
    checkIfLoaded();
    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

then i just write a like button in the html :

```
<div id="page" class="page-01">
    <div id="content">
        <h1><a href="#"><img src="img/skin/logo.png" alt=""/></a></h1>
        <div class="block-01">
            <div id="fb-root"></div>
            <div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="105" data-show-faces="false"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

</div>
```

I was expecting a like on my application by this button, but it like the url hosting my application.

I'm new to js sdk, is there a way to do this kind of things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "Liking Application", actually the only thing you can bound your Like Button is URL (which may represent OpenGraph object).

You cannot use Like Button to like any internal Facebook Objects like Page, Application, User, etc.

If you speaking about liking the Page that associated with specific Application you should use  [Like Box social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box) (which is intended to be used with Pages).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i was looking for page like. Like box seems to do the job, but isn't easily customisable, i need the like count to be in a little tooltip, like original like button count.

Comment: there's a little something i still don't understand, my app checks in php if ($signed['page']['liked'] == 1) { where $signed is the signed_request parsed to display the main screen, and a screen with a like button if the user don't like. Even if the js like button like the page, the screen isn't changing at all.

Comment: `$signed['page']['liked'` is only populated on request, once your user liked the page you will need to reload the tab application.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the URL to like with data-href="url to like"